# How to filter a dataframe and update selective rows for a particular cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update a particular column in DF when certain condition on another column passes . this is what I am trying but it gives error

```py
train[train['Rain]'==1]['Price']=100
```

So for all rows when Rain column is 1 , for that Row the price column should be set to 100 , could you give an example of using it via where and without where fucntion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could use below three options**

```
train.loc[train['Rain'] == 1, ['Price']] = 100
```

OR

```
import numpy as np
train['Price'] = np.where(train['Rain'] == 1, 100,train['Price'])
```

OR use the 'at' operator

```
train.at[train['Rain'] == 1, ['Price']] = 100
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Dataframe.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
train.loc[train['Rain'] == 1, ['Price']] = 100
```